# htmlagilitypack get form action attribute

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using htmlagilitypack to get the content of a website. I'm looking for the content inside form action.

I can get the form by the code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(urlAddress);

var form = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@class='picker']");
```

Now, is there any way to get the content inside action tag of my form?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the action property of the `<form>` tag, then you just need to check the Attributes property of your HtmlNode object (form):

```
string actionValue = form.Attributes["action"]?.Value;
```

Even if you did not want to look through the [source on Github](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack), you can easily find an example of this in their [tutorials](http://html-agility-pack.net/select-single-node).